# Bind Google Analytic's Data Feed to Google Charts

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-visualization

i have used Google Analytic API Version 3 and i can get data from it with this C# codes:

```
DataQuery _chartquery = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
        _chartquery.Ids = str;
        _chartquery.Dimensions = "ga:date";
        _chartquery.Metrics = "ga:pageviews";
        _chartquery.Sort = "ga:date";
        _chartquery.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        _chartquery.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DataFeed _chartfeed = service.Query(_chartquery);
```

here i can get `_charfeed` as DataFeed, now i want to bind this feed to Google chart, can you tell me how should do this?